# A Double Limit Question

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

Maybe it's easy, but: Is it true that

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$$

If it is, could you help me prove it?

Thanks

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572125/show-discontinuity-of-fracxyx2y2/572148#572148 would give you some idea (with some other example)......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the function $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, **the limit exists**. To see why, find a bound that trivially tends toward 0:

$$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \le \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2}} = |x| \to 0$$

For the function $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, **the limit does not exist**.

To see why, find two paths that tend toward (0,0) for which the limit is different (if the limit exists, it must be the same whatever the path).

Let $y=\lambda x$ and $x > 0$, then

$$ \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+\lambda^2x^2}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 (1+\lambda^2)}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda^2}}$$

Thus the function is constant and obviously "tends" toward $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda^2}}$, which will vary with $\lambda$. Hence the limit does not exist.

Note: of course, the function of $x$ alone (that is, with $y=\lambda x$) is only constant for $x > 0$. For $x<0$, the constant is negative, $- \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda^2}}$, since in this case $\frac{x}{|x|} = -1$.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the question, it should be $x$ on the numerator instead of $x^2$.

Comment: $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\to0$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, perhaps simpler: use polar coordinates

$$x=r\cos\theta\;,\;\;y=r\sin\theta\;,\;\;\text{and observe that}\;\;(x,y)\to 0\implies r\to 0\;,\;\;\text{so}$$

$$\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{r\cos\theta}{r}=\cos\theta\xrightarrow[r\to 0]{}\cos\theta$$

and the limit depends on $\;\theta\;$ and thus it cannot exist .