# Prove that the function $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}$ is continuous except on $(0,0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

How can I prove that the function $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}$ is continuous except on $(0,0)$? I was able to prove that this function is bounded by $\frac{1}{2}$, but I still do not know how to prove its continuity.

Comment: Continuity can be shown at other points, by showing continuity in both variables seperately, as function is defined at that points (even if you take one to be a function of another). at (0,0) just take several pathes that lead to distinct limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that you are able to show discontinuity at $(0,0)$ - and there are also some other posts on this site about this: [Show discontinuity of $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572125/show-discontinuity-of-fracxyx2y2)

Continuity in other points follows from this fact:

> If both $g(x,y)$ and $h(x,y)$ are continuous at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ and $h(x_0,y_0)\ne0$ then also the function
>   $$f(x,y)=\frac{g(x,y)}{h(x,y)}$$
>   is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$.

Answer (score 3):

For discontinuity at the origin, polar coordinates do the trick quite quickly
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{r^2\sin \theta \cos \theta}{r^2}=\sin \theta \cos \theta
$$
which is not independent of choice of theta.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try doing the limit along $(x=t;y=mt)$ with $t\to 0$. It will depend on $m$!